# PHP Convert to YouTube Time Format (ISO 8601)

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetime-format, iso8601

The time format I want is `2016-01-19T06:22:00.000Z` (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ); however, I am getting this format: `2016-01-19T06:22:00+01:00`.

Here is my code:

```
$before = "2016-01-19 06:22:00";
$after = date('c', strtotime($before));

echo "Before: $before\n";
echo "After: $after";
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://ideone.com/Occ9zJ).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#115228

Comment: @CBroe, thanks, but `$after = (new DateTime($before))->format(DateTime::ISO8601);` produces `2016-01-19T06:22:00+0100`. I need it to be in a format exactly like this `2016-01-19T06:22:00.000Z` as YouTube is not accepting it from me in other formats.

Comment: Well then you can easily create it yourself, by putting the individual date parts that the other format characters stand for together in the right order.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe. `$after = str_replace('+', '.', (new DateTime($before))->format(DateTime::ISO8601))."Z";` works, but it's not elegant. However, Mihai's answer works perfectly and is elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$before = "2016-01-19 06:22:00";
$after = (new DateTime($before))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.s\Z');

echo "Before: $before\n";
echo "After: $after";
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this:

```
$before = "2016-01-19 06:22:00";
$format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO';
$after = date($format, strtotime($before));

echo "Before: $before<br/>";
echo "After: $after";
```

Comment: Thanks. That is closer than what I was originally using, but still returns `2016-01-19T06:22:00.000000+0100` instead. I was looking for something like Mihai's answer.